# Password Protect Page using .htaccess

Tags: centos, html

I followed simple [steps](http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/)  to make a password protected webpage, but it does not work i.e. I can open the page from any browser and it does not ask me to login to view the page. 
The .htaccess file looks like this

```
AuthUserFile PATH/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Please Login"
AuthType Basic
<Files "index.html">
require valid-user
</Files>
```

and the .htpasswd file contains `username:encrypted password`

UPDATE: This [article](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/set-up-basic-authentication-in-apache-using-htaccess-on-centos-7/) helped me to fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authtype):

```
AuthBasicProvider file
```

Also check that Apache is allowed to read your .htaccess file via `AllowOverride` ([link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride))

Comment: I was changing the  line from `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride AuthConfig` in the section that begins with `<Directory >` instead of `<Directory "/var/www/html">`.